# Rails generate fixtures from existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures

I have big database (more than 100 tables, more than 5GB)

Is there a possibility to generate related fixtures for testing from this database, just about 3-5 records per table (but with neeeded relations)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Better to use Factories than fixtures.

Check out [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails)

With factories you can create test records as and when required. They'll automatically build the necessary related objects too.

So if you have **Post** with many **Comments** you just have to call `Factory(:create, :comment)` which will create a valid Comment and it's parent Post.